# JavaScript Math Operations and Inputting Into Text Field Live

Tags: javascript, addition

I'm a little new to JS.

I'm attempting to take 3 text fields and add them and then multiply their value by a drop down field with a percentage in it. Once that's done I want it to populate the final text field with a value.

So far I haven't even been able to get the text to display in the final field much less add it together. I'd appreciate it if anyone could help point me in the right direction.

```
Our Buying Cost:
<input id="buying_cost" name="buying_cost" type="text" />
<br/>Our Shipping Cost:
<input id="shipping_cost" name="shipping_cost" type="text" />
<br/>Our Tax Cost:
<input id="tax_cost" name="tax_cost" type="text" />
<br/>Our Markup:
<select id="markup" name="markup" value="">
    <option value="0">0%</option>
    <option value="10">10%</option>
    <option value="20">20%</option>
    <option value="30">30%</option>
    <option value="40">40%</option>
    <option value="50">50%</option>
    <option value="60">60%</option>
    <option value="70">70%</option>
    <option value="80">80%</option>
    <option value="90">90%</option>
    <option value="100">100%</option>
</select>
<br/>
<p>New Selling Price:</p>
<input type="text" id="new_sell_price" name="new_sell_price" value="">





$("#buying_cost,#shipping_cost,#tax_cost,#markup).change(function () 
{
    var addressArray = [$("#buying_cost").val(), $("#shipping_cost").val(), $("#tax_cost").val(), $("#markup").val()];
    $("#new_sell_price").text(addressArray.join(' '));//<--I would like this to be adding all the values
}

);
```

I've included the work here at this JSFiddle

jsfiddle.net/new2programming/hy99yu2m/

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're missing a " before ').change(function ()'

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more, I'm not sure where to start with that?

Comment: you have a typo in there. Change `#markup).change(` to `#markup").change(`

Comment: And you really should have your javascript console out at all times, and check it for every problem you get before asking for help. Your code above would've given you an error and you should have been able to trace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a clean and simple solution for your problem: [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hy99yu2m/2/)

**But pay attention, you should not copy-paste this code if you don't really understand what exactly it does!**

First of all, register the events:

```
// I recommend jQuery.on(...) on the document
$(document).on('input', 'input', calculate);
$(document).on('change', 'select,input', calculate);
// use the 'input' event for a live update
// and the 'change' value for a secure update
```

*(You can replace 'input' and 'select,input' with the jQuery-selector of your elements if you want so, read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/))*

In the next step, you fill your array with all your values:

```
var values = [
    $("#buying_cost").val(), 
    $("#shipping_cost").val(), 
    $("#tax_cost").val(), 
    $("#markup").val()
];
```

Now you can addition all the values in the array:

```
var total = eval( values.join('+') );
// the eval function calculates the given string (generated by the join function)
```

And for the last step, you set the calculated value:

```
$("#new_sell_price").val(total);
// use 'val(...)' and not 'text(...)' because you want to set the value and not the text!
```

Comment: Thank you that worked out nicely! It forces the value into the text field rather than puts it in there and allows me to erase it. Any thoughts on how to make it deleteable in that last text field?

Comment: Change the selector-events (in the on-event) just to the editable selectors or try the following: http://jsfiddle.net/hy99yu2m/7/